# "Line 302 Permission Denied" error while installing VMware Player

Tags: installation, permissions, vmware

### The Problem

For an Operating Systems Architecture course at University, we are required to use VMware Player 3.1.4 for class assignments. I currently run 64-bit Ubuntu 11.04, and have recently formatted with a vanilla install of 64-bit 11.04; which still had the following outcome.

I start the install off by cd'ing to the directory where the VMware bundle resides and running this installation command:

```
sudo sh ./VMware-Player-3.1.4-385536.x86_64.bundle
```

Unfortunately, after half of a second of running the install script, I encounter this error:

> ./VMware-Player-3.1.4-385536.x86_64.bundle: line 302: /tmp/vmis.k6Yk9O/install/vmware-installer/vmware-installer: Permission denied

At which the extracted installer is executed at line 302 with the following options:

```
302     "$installer" --set-setting vmware-installer libconf "$libconf"   \
303                  --install-component "$source"/vmware-installer      \
304                  --install-bundle "$bundle" "$@"
```

Also, an md5sum called on the bundle returns the exact sum as mentioned on the download page.

> a7fdadfb2af8d9f76571cd06f2439041  VMware-Player-3.1.4-385536.x86_64.bundle

At this point, I've used `sudo -i` to log in as root which still throws a permission denied error.
Searching Google and Stackoverflow provided only [one other case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733110/installing-vmware-player-3-1-4-385536-x86-64-bundle-bundle-vmware-player) with no answers (I upvoted); so I decided to post to askubuntu wondering if somebody has had the same issue or has a fix under 11.04?

Cheers! :P

Comment: Alex - the partition that holds your /tmp folder, does it have a "noexec" in /etc/fstab - I think that may cause this issue.

Comment: Haha, oh man... You must be dead on the head with this one... Yeah, I've mounted my /tmp to ram using `nodev,nosuid,noexec,mode=1777` - I'll boot up my 64-bit and try it out :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is likely that the installer is trying to execute a binary in the /tmp folder.

It is probable that whatever partition you have your /tmp folder in, it is configured in /etc/fstab to be "[noexec](http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/fstab.html)".  This means that no binaries are allowed to be executed on that partition.

My advice is to move /tmp to its own partition that has "exec" rights in your fstab line options.

Alternatively, temporarily change "noexec" to "exec" in fstab - install vmware and then switch it back again.